# How to set hotkey to auto type copied text from clipboard by AutoHotkey?

Tags: automation, copy, autohotkey, hotkeys

I'm using AHK. But I don't know any script help me type text from clipboard (I chosen text and ctrl+C).

Can you help me?!

Thank you!

Comment: I want to auto fill in sellect dropdown menu from a text value in chrome. And type text copied is the fastest way to do it without more code

Answer (score 1):

You should check help for "Clipboard" and find that this works:

```
Send %Clipboard%
```

Here are some details:

`Clipboard` and `ClipboardAll`

`Clipboard` is a built-in variable that reflects the current contents of the Windows clipboard if those contents can be expressed as text. By contrast, `ClipboardAll` contains everything on the clipboard, such as pictures and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you dislike my question. But i know AHK is created to provide automatic solution to boost performence icluded illegal. Ok?
This is my search in forum AHK. If you tested, let me know your experience!

```
"
; win + v

#v::

  SendRaw %clipboard%
                        "
```